# Segment of string does not work in "if" statement

Tags: python

I am working on a piece of a program in which I need to search for a string within a text file and print out the line that it is found in. I am having a problem with the following line:

```
if ingredient[8:] in line :
```

Nothing ends up being printed out, unless I manually type in the string that is held in ingredient[8:]. For example:

```
if "tomato" in line :
```

This works perfectly. I can't seem to figure out why "tomato" or "lentil" would work instead of "ingredient[8:]".

The following is my code:

```
# VARIABLES
shoppingList=[]

# MOVE CONTENTS OF SHOPPING LIST FILE ONTO LIST
with open("Recipe Shopping List.txt") as f:
    content = f.readlines()

def findRecipe():

    # PROMPT USER FOR RECIPE NAME
    print "Enter a recipe name: "
    recipeInput = raw_input()
    recipeIndex = content.index("  - " + recipeInput + "\n")

    # PUT INGREDIENTS INTO SHOPPING LIST
    for ingredient in content[recipeIndex+1:]:
        if ingredient.startswith("    -"):
            # FIND INGREDIENT'S CATEGORY IN CATEGORY FILE   
            with open("Ingredient Category List.txt") as categoryFile :
                for line in categoryFile :
                    if ingredient[8:] in line :
                        print line
        else:
            break

findRecipe()
```

And here is the text stored in the test text files:

**"Ingredient Category List.txt"**

```
tomato - produce
carrot - produce
celery - produce
lentil - grains
```

**"Recipe Shopping List.txt"**

```
  - Lentil soup
    - 2 lentil
    - 3 tomato
    - 4 celery
    - 4 carrot
  - Gnocchi
    - 1 tomato
    - 3 gnocchi
    - 2 onion
```

Thank you in advance for any help.

Comment: @leaf Thanks for your response. `ingredient` is supposed to hold strings like "    - 2 lentil" so I was trying to reference the substring that just contains the name of the food, so I thought `ingredient[8:]` would just be "lentil" in this case. When I print `ingredient[8:]`, I do get "lentil" and it's of type str.

Comment: My bad. I just realized my mistake. I'll delete my comment.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**ingredient[8:]** includes the line feed.  Chop it one character short:

```
if ingredient[8:-1] in line:
```

Better yet, split the line and pull out the one field you need, nicely stripped of white space.

Answer (score 1):

```
ingredients[8:]
```

This line is returning the new line as well, so for example, instead of:

```
'lentil'
```

it's returning:

```
'lentil
'
```

You can change the line to:

```
ingredients[8:].rstrip()
```

Comment: Thank you! It's really good to know about the rstrip() method.